# I accepted a package for a neighbor which damaged my property. Who is responsible?

Tags: liability, germany, mail

Imagine I accepted a package for a neighbor. The content of the box (for an example case, let's say it was a strong magnet) damaged some of my possessions.

Let's say, I placed the box on my computer because I couldn't have known what was inside the box, and couldn't have figured it out without breaking law.

So now storing the box is damaging and/or destroying parts of my computer, just by being placed on it.

Who is responsible for this damage?

Comment: As far as I understand, you can't accept mail that isn't assigned to you, unless you reside in the same dwelling, but I'm not so sure of that.

Comment: @Zizouz212: I can't speak for other nations, but in germany it is admissible to sign for your neighbor in his absence and your neighbor will get just an card that informs who accepted it for him. If you don't want it to happen you have explicitly in writing notify the mail service that you dont want them to do this.

Comment: @Zaibis - You accepted the package willingly, you weren't compelled to do so by the owner, therefore, you are at fault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nobody could have reasonably foreseen that damage.

If the magnets are strong enough though, they are considered a dangerous good, and that brings a bunch of packaging, paperwork, and shipping requirements that would prevent the situation you describe.

Comment: Ok this would mean under the line I just had bad luck and had to replace my broken stuf my self?

Comment: Yes you do, bad luck

Comment: @Zaibis Perhaps check your renter's or homeowner's insurance policy - they might cover accidental damage of the sort you describe.